# Is it possible to use jmeter on a local app?

Tags: jmeter, local

Jmeter seems to be a very promising tool.
But it always speaks about 'web apps' and I just want to do test perf on a local machine for a particular running app. Like visualVM can do but with parsable logs.
If I can do that the other possibilities with jmeter are great so I won't be limited on my testes.
There ismentions of localhost web application but I jsut want to make it analyze a local running app, not a web app.
If not possible I would like to know which apps can do perf tests for local apps.

Thanks for reading me.

I tried to run jmeter GUI but all the options I choose leads me to request with ip or external adresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean desktop application, JMeter is not something which can help you, you should rather go for a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) specific for the language/technology which was used for creating the "local" application.

JMeter can help you to simulate hundreds/thousands of "local" apps which are concurrently accessing the backend or a database, this way you will be able to mimic "local" app's network footprint and replay it with increased load. If this is something you're looking for - check out [How to Do Desktop Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/desktop-performance-testing) article